# How to substitute string coming from django in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Suppose this is a part of my django template:

```
<div class="txt"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var text = '{{ each.text }}'
    $('.txt').html(text);
    });
</script>
```

So this code is messing my output.Suppose the string returned by django to this template is `This is great'thing`.So here the output is only `This is great`.So how can I escape quotes and blockquotes in javascript?

Comment: Never used django, but check if it's got a JSON encoder. Pass your strings through that to guarantee you end up with syntactically valid javascript data you can safely insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `escapejs` filter:

```
var text = '{{ each.text | escapejs }}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how to escape html text in template.
Refer [template filter escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape)